# Why can't I implement a parametrized interface mutiple times with different parameters?

Tags: java

I'm developing a system where widgets listen for changes in some model. I wanted to notify widgets over an interface parametrized with notification's class. Why doesn't Java allow this:

```
public class UiInventory extends Widget implements 
    Observer<EventGetItem>, 
    Observer<EventLoseItem>, 
    Observer<EventWield>, 
    Observer<EventUnwield>, 
    Observer<EventPutOn>, 
    Observer<EventTakeOff> {
```

The error message is simply Duplicate class: 'my.package.structure.Observer', but why does it appear in the first place?

Comment: Because type erasure exists. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+interface+cannot+be+implemented+more+than+once+with+different+arguments

Comment: Oh, right, a complete duplicate. Should I delete the question?

Comment: [No.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/133242)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in [Java's type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  At runtime, generic type information is erased, and this would just result in

```
public class UiInventory extends Widget implements 
  Observer, 
  Observer, 
  Observer, 
  Observer, 
  Observer, 
  Observer {
```

which you cannot do.  Any generic type parameters in methods would resolve to `Object` and you'd get duplicate method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that compiler would let you implement your interface few times

```
interface MyInterface<T>{
   T getValue();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface<Integer>, MyInterface<String>{
    ??? getValue(){

    }
}
```

What type of value should be returned in `getValue`? Integer? String?

Even if your interface wouldn't have any generics methods then because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) your class would be compiled into

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface, MyInterface{//no <Inger> or <String> here

}
```

which doesn't really have any point.